# Issue connecting to Azure Cognitive Services Bing Web Search API-'Resource Not Found'

Tags: azure, python3, bing

I cannot connect to Azures Bing Web Search API though Cognitive Services. I followed everything in the setup guide but when i run the QuickStart script with freshly created subscription key and endpoint path i get the following:

error:azure.cognitiveservices.search.websearch.models.error_response_py3.ErrorResponseException: Operation returned an invalid status code 'Resource Not Found'

Any ideas would be most appreciated? 
Thanks

Comment: same problem here